# Exported DLL function has only stdcall with some offset

Tags: ida, windows, dll

I am quite new to reverse engineering. I have opened .dll (x86) in IDA Pro and I have noticed few exported functions. The issue is that all of them looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

IDA pseudocode:

```
int __stdcall GameLauncher_StartGameW(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, int a7)
{
  return (*(int (__stdcall **)(int, int, int, int, int, int))(*(_DWORD *)a1 + 8))(a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7);
}
```

If I understand this correctly I need to get a1 object (eax) to actually get the function that I want to reverse engineer. Am I right? Is there any easy way to get this object to get the function offset?

Comment: it is an exported entry so the int a1 may not be available at all if you are looking statically if the function was never called from that specific dll . you may need to look at the associated Executables to see who or where this function is called from there you may eke out the argument that is passed  It appears it is a vtable pointer and +8 is a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be just to set a breakpoint where the `call` instruction is and then perform *step into* - you will be redirected to the right function.

You can also check it statically assuming that you know where the `GameLauncher_StartGameW` is called. Notice that  just before `call [eax+8]`, `eax` contains `*arg0` value. If you know the arguments' values, you will also get the address of the function being called.

Comment: Thanks! I used x64dbg and added breakpoint. I have the right function now.

Comment: You are welcome.